# Restrict Which Node a Jenkins Job can be Run On, but only allow this field to be modified by Administrator

Tags: jenkins, configure, restrict

I know that you can restrict where a project is run, by filling in that field in in a Job. I was hoping to find a way to allow individual users who have configuration access to the job to still be able to edit the rest of the job, but to remove this field from their view. I would like only the System Administrator to be able to modify it. The reason for doing this is we currently have a number of nodes set up that are tied to individual users and I want to prevent one user from running on another user's node (aka running as the other user), but I still want the user to be able to change other parts of their job.

Comment: Are you afraid that they'll do it on purpose or by accident?

Answer (score 1):

As much as i know the security system, you can just allow all user to edit the job, or allow specific users to edit the job.
once you can edit the job, you can edit all of the fields available and there is no way to restrict specific configuration value.

I think letting all users edit jobs permission is not a good practice, and if i had to let all users have some kind of control it would be using parameters that you can add.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. We've found through our initial trial with a sub-set of our team that let the users edit their own jobs has been very beneficial in terms of them coming up with improvements as well as buying into the utility of Jenkins as a whole. If we have to lock down the entire job, then maybe we'll go down that route, but I'm still hoping to avoid it. Thanks again